# Is there such a thing as 'onion hair'?

Tags: language

I've been reading a food menu of a Qatari hotel, and I've come across the following dish description:

> Roasted stuffed quails (3) with ***golden onion hair*** and green pepper

Naturally, searching Google, all I could find was results about how good onion is for hair growth.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a bad translation... is there an original description or an image?

Comment: unfortunately no. I got it as a plain text. think it's wrong, just wanted to make sure

Comment: A guess would be very thin and deep fried (golden brown) onion strings. Like these: https://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/ree-drummond/beer-battered-onion-strings-3091495

Comment: I've no answer to what they mean by 'golden onion hair', but want to thank SnakeDoc for the link to Ree's recipe. It looks good and I'll try :-)